# Create trigger for Lambda function using Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

How do I create an Alexa trigger for a Lambda function using boto3 in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who may not know how.

```
response = client.add_permission(
    FunctionName='<YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME>',
    StatementId='AlexaFunctionPermission',
    Action='lambda:InvokeFunction',
    Principal='alexa-appkit.amazon.com',)
```

Answer (score 2):

To update the accepted answer a bit (mid-2018):

Nowadays, for *Skill ID Verification*, you can add an `EventSourceToken` parameter (see [boto3 docs on `add_permission()`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.add_permission))

```
function_name = 'foo'
skill_id ='amzn1.ask.skill.xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
response = client.add_permission(
    FunctionName=function_name,
    StatementId='AlexaFunctionPermission',
    Action='lambda:InvokeFunction',
    Principal='alexa-appkit.amazon.com',
    EventSourceToken=skill_id)
```

See the [official reference (CLI-based)](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/host-a-custom-skill-as-an-aws-lambda-function.html#use-aws-cli).

Hope that helps someone.