# Using AWS CDK, how can one alter a resource after its creation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, aws-cdk

I am using AWS CDK to create a Cognito User Pool with a few lambda triggers. One of the lambdas requires a role to be attached that depends on the user pool arn. I have achieved this behaviour by adding the user pool to this particular lambda's dependencies. The problem is that I had to remove this lambda from the user pool's lambda triggers in order to avoid a circular dependency. I am struggling to find a way to add this trigger AFTER the creation of the lambda. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
    const userPool = new cg.UserPool(this, "users", {
      ...
      lambdaTriggers: {
        ...lambdas with no dependencies
      },
    });

    // makeLambda is a custom function that returns new lambda.Function
    const postAuthentication = makeLambda(this, "postAuthentication");

    postAuthentication.addToRolePolicy(
      new iam.PolicyStatement({
        effect: iam.Effect.ALLOW,
        actions: ["cognito-idp:AdminUpdateUserAttributes"],
        resources: [userPool.userPoolArn],
      })
    );

    postAuthentication.node.addDependency(userPool);

    // This line of code is what is causing the circular dependency, if I could find a
       a way to delay this step until after the creation of the lambda it would
       solve the problem
    userPool.addTrigger(cg.UserPoolOperation.POST_AUTHENTICATION, postAuthentication);
```

Comment: https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/7016

Answer (score -1):

You need to construct `userPool.userPoolArn` yourself as a string, instead of referencing the resource. You'll need to be able to predict the exact arn, which might require hard coding a name for the user pool.

Comment: The arn seems to follow the format:
 arn:aws:cognito-idp:<REGION>:<ACCOUNT>:userpool/<USER_POOL_ID>.

When I supply a name for the user pool, it does not have any effect on the user pool id - it seems to simply be a concatenation of the region with a random string.

Is there any other way we could predict the arn?

Answer (score -1):

try boto3;

from;
[Create trigger for Lambda function using Boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40748683/create-trigger-for-lambda-function-using-boto3)

```
response = client.add_permission(
    FunctionName='<YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME>',
    StatementId='AlexaFunctionPermission',
    Action='lambda:InvokeFunction',
    Principal='alexa-appkit.amazon.com',)
```